# How to substitute a subset of string from a string?

Tags: r

I am trying to remove "+(1|v)" from "yclass ~ x+e+(1|v)" in R Can anyone please tell me how to do it??
I have tried to use sub function in R but it replaces just the first letter of matched string

Comment: since it's a fixed string you want to remove: `sub("+(1|v)", "", x, fixed=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string, can use `sub`

```
sub("\\+\\(.*", "", str1)
#[1] "yclass ~ x+e"
```

---

If it is just a formula

```
f2 <- reformulate(all.vars(f1)[2:3], f1[[2]])
f2
#yclass ~ x + e
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "yclass ~ x+e+(1|v)" 
f1 <- yclass ~ x+e+(1|v)
```